# I am unable to use CSS positioning to move or reposition my select2

Tags: html, css

i need help here, used select2 which is hosted from a CDN together with its styling sheet, but now i am trying to re position my drop down and its not moving which i know for sure it has to do with the styling sheet, it ignore the values i assign but rather use the ones from  the CDN, is there anyway i can use both of them to style my select?

here is my select, i did not make a separate styling sheet but just incorporated it within the HTML

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


    <title>Disease serach</title>
</head>

<select class="disease" style="width: 30%;  position: relative;top: -220px; left: 182px; " name="tdisease" >
                            <option value="">Select Disease</option>
                             <?php while ($row=$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $row['ICD10']?>"><?php echo $row['diagnosis'];?> </option> 
                      <?php } ?> 
                         </select>
```

and the Jquery

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(".disease").select2({
  allowClear:true,
  placeholder: 'Search for a disease'
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can override styles like this:

1. Load your own CSS after the one from the CDN
2. Use a CSS specificity that is the same or higher than that of the style you want to override
3. Write your style

Comment: no matter how high i set the values it just can not override it

Comment: What exactly do you do when you "set the values higher"?

Comment: um
#disease {

 position: relative;
 top: 500px;
 left: 700px;

}

Comment: you are using the hash selector --> that is for id's. use .disease.